# Mysqli_num_row not generating the database row correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to get the row of my email in my database and I use the query so I can validate the email in my database and I used the code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $num = 1;

    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'user_managment';


    $connection = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE email = 'user@gmail.com'");
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query) == $num;
    if ($result){
        echo 'Yes';
    }else{
        echo 'No';
    }
}
```

my database is here and I only have an email(alex@gmail.com)

[image]

but I do the notice these still echo out 'yes' whenever I insert email that ain't in my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you do `COUNT(*)`, this will always result in a single record.

A better solution would be:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
   echo "Yes";
} else {
   echo "No";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: please can you answer these in procedural as well

Comment: It is not about the style, it is about the solution. Setting it to procedural should be trivial (and a good exercise ;-)).

Comment: you are correct actually but i don't actually understand the sql query well on how u solve it